# Project Reactor: How to control Flux emission

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I have a flux that emits some `Date`. This `Date` is mapped to 1024 simulated HTTP requests that I'm running on some `Executer`.

What I'd like to do is waiting for all the 1024 HTTP requests before emitting the next `Date`.

Currently when running, `onNext()` is called for many times and then it is stabilised on some steady rate.

How can I change this behaviour?

P.S. I'm willing to change to architecture, if needed.

```
private void run() throws Exception {

    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    Flux<Date> source = Flux.generate(emitter ->
        emitter.next(new Date())
    );

    source
            .log()
            .limitRate(1)
            .doOnNext(date -> System.out.println("on next: " + date))
            .map(date -> Flux.range(0, 1024))
            .flatMap(i -> Mono.fromCallable(Pipeline::simulateHttp)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor)))
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));

    Thread.currentThread().join();
}
```

HTTP request simulation:

```
private static String simulateHttp() {
    try {
        System.out.println("start http call");
        Thread.sleep(3_000);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return "HTML content";
}
```

**EDIT: adapted code from answer:**

- First, I had a bug in my code (another `flatMap` was needed)
- Second, I added `concurrency` parameter of `1` to both `flatMap` (it seems that both are needed)

  ```
  Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  Flux<Date> source = Flux.generate(emitter -> {
      System.out.println("emitter called!");
      emitter.next(new Date());
  });

  source
          .limitRate(1)
          .map(date -> Flux.range(0, 16))
          .flatMap(Function.identity(), 1) # concurrency = 1
          .flatMap(i -> Mono.fromCallable(Pipeline::simulateHttp)
                  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executor)), 1) # concurrency = 1
          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));

  Thread.currentThread().join();
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at these methods:

- [`Flux.flatMap(Function, int, int)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-int-)
- [`Flux.concatMap(Function, int)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-).

`concatMap` ensures that the elements on the flux are processed sequentially inside the operator:

> Generation of inners and subscription: **this operator waits for one
>   inner to complete before generating the next one** and subscribing to
>   it.

`flatMap` lets you do the same by exposing `concurrency` and `prefetch` parameters which provide you more control over this behavior:

> The concurrency argument allows to control how many Publisher can be
>   subscribed to and merged in parallel. In turn, that argument shows the
>   size of the first Subscription.request(long) to the upstream. The
>   prefetch argument allows to give an arbitrary prefetch size to the
>   merged Publisher (in other words prefetch size means the size of the
>   first Subscription.request(long) to the merged Publisher).